# How to fill anchor onclick with correct data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looping over inputs where I get the value from and want to use this to

Here is the html of the inputs

```
<div class="follow-inputs text-center">
   <div class="input-group my-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
         <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
           <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
         </span>
      </div>
      <input id="facebook" class="form-control follow-url-inputs" name="facebook" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes">
   </div><br>
   <div class="input-group my-2">
     <div class="input-group-prepend">
       <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
         <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
       </span>
     </div>
     <input id="linkedin" class="form-control follow-url-inputs" name="linkedin" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes">
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-group my-2">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
          <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input id="twitter" class="form-control follow-url-inputs" name="twitter" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes">
    </div>
    <br>
 </div>
```

assign it to an anchor onclick event like this:

```
$('.follow-url-inputs').each(function(index, item){
    console.log(index, $(item).val(), $('#socialShare a', index));
    $('#socialShare a').attr("onclick", "window.open('" + $(item).val() + "')");
})
```

This is the html of the socialshare bar:

```
<div class="socialShare" data-top1="150" data-top2="20" data-margin="0">
   <span id="socialShare" style="position: fixed; z-index: 9999; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 5px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 10px 0px; margin-left: 0px; top: 20px;">
     <a rel="nofollow" class="shareBtns" href="#" id="fs_facebook-btn" data-count="facebook" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsharebtns.fingerspitz.nl.ebox%2F', '_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0');return false" title="Share on Facebook" target="_self"></a>
     <a rel="nofollow" class="shareBtns" href="#" id="fs_linkedin-btn" data-count="linkedin" onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fsharebtns.fingerspitz.nl.ebox%2F&amp;title=BetterAddThis%20-%20Gratis%20social%20share%20buttons', '_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=600, height=400, toolbar=0, status=0');return false" title="Share on Linkedin" target="_self"></a>
     <a rel="nofollow" class="shareBtns" href="#" id="fs_twitter-btn" data-count="twitter" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=BetterAddThis%20-%20Gratis%20social%20share%20buttons&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fsharebtns.fingerspitz.nl.ebox%2F', '_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0');return false" title="Share on Twitter" ;="" target="_self"></a>
   </span>
</div>
```

But it fills all the `#socialShare a` with the last `$(item).val()` value. How can I fill the anchor window open with the correct data instead of only the last one?

Comment: When you do `$('#socialShare a')` it targets all of the anchors and this happens every time you loop thru the inputs so only the last input value is there after it is done

Comment: You'll need to use a more specific selector than `$("#socialShare a")`, but it will depend on your html layout and how the new link relates to `.follow-url-inputs`, eg it might be `$(this).next("a")`.  But no way for us to know.

Comment: It's only using the last value because every time you set the `onclick` attribute, you are overriding the previous value. Do you have multiple elements you want to change? Do you want that one to open multiple windows?

Comment: @Huangism so lets say I have three input values with: 1,2,3 and three `#socialShare a` how can I fill the onclick attr of these `#socialShare a` from first to third with 1-2-3

Comment: As stated above, you need to know the relation between them.  Or you could just do a hacky `$('#socialShare a').eq(index).attr...`

Comment: Side note, you don't have to put the url as an onclick.  You can set the href of the link and the set the `target` attribute to something, which will cause it to open in a new window/tab.

Comment: Post the accompanying html - I think that would help us help you greatly.

Comment: edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, as I mentioned in comments, is that you are currently targeting all anchors and replacing the value each time you go thru the loop so you end up with the same value for all anchors (the last value in the loop)

To fix this with your current html structure:

You can use `.eq()` and pass it the index, since your anchors matches up with the inputs

If you inspect the results, you will see the onclick has been changed. If you set a value to the input it should change to those values (when loading). I added a value of `test` to the first input and 1, 2 and 3 for the anchors so it is easier to see

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

If your anchors tags are not in the same order as your inputs, you could use data attributes to target the corresponding anchors

```js
$('.follow-url-inputs').each(function(index, item) {
  $('#socialShare a').eq(index).attr("onclick", "window.open('" + $(item).val() + "')");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="follow-inputs text-center">
  <div class="input-group my-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
           <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
         </span>
    </div>
    <input id="facebook" class="form-control follow-url-inputs" name="facebook" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes" value="test">
  </div><br>
  <div class="input-group my-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
         <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
       </span>
    </div>
    <input id="linkedin" class="form-control follow-url-inputs" name="linkedin" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes">
  </div><br>
  <div class="input-group my-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
          <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <input id="twitter" class="form-control follow-url-inputs" name="twitter" data-com.agilebits.onepassword.user-edited="yes">
  </div>
  <br>
</div>

<div class="socialShare" data-top1="150" data-top2="20" data-margin="0">
  <span id="socialShare" style="position: fixed; z-index: 9999; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 5px; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 0px 10px 0px; margin-left: 0px; top: 20px;">
     <a rel="nofollow" class="shareBtns" href="#" id="fs_facebook-btn" data-count="facebook" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsharebtns.fingerspitz.nl.ebox%2F', '_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0');return false" title="Share on Facebook" target="_self">1</a>
     <a rel="nofollow" class="shareBtns" href="#" id="fs_linkedin-btn" data-count="linkedin" onclick="window.open('https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fsharebtns.fingerspitz.nl.ebox%2F&amp;title=BetterAddThis%20-%20Gratis%20social%20share%20buttons', '_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=600, height=400, toolbar=0, status=0');return false" title="Share on Linkedin" target="_self">2</a>
     <a rel="nofollow" class="shareBtns" href="#" id="fs_twitter-btn" data-count="twitter" onclick="window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=BetterAddThis%20-%20Gratis%20social%20share%20buttons&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fsharebtns.fingerspitz.nl.ebox%2F', '_blank', 'scrollbars=0, resizable=1, menubar=0, left=100, top=100, width=550, height=440, toolbar=0, status=0');return false" title="Share on Twitter" ;="" target="_self">3</a>
   </span>
</div>
```